# Adding subscripts to differential equations using solve_ivp

Tags: python, indexing, scipy, differential-equations, subscript

Click this link to see the model: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CDKKO.png
I am trying to model the set of differential equations as shown in the photo of the link above. It is the goodwin oscillator model, and for some reason, I am unable to code for the subscripts of the model. My code looks like this and you will notice the "i" subscript is omitted. **"i" = 1,2,...,N**

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
from scipy.integrate import solve_ivp

def model(t, y):
    X,Y,Z,V,F = y
    v1 = 0.7; K1 = 1.0; n = 4.0; v2 = 0.35; K2 = 1.0; k3 = 
    0.7; v4 = 0.35; K4 = 1.0; k5 = 0.7
    v6 = 0.35; K6 = 1.0; k7 = 0.35; v8 = 1.0; K8 = 1.0; vc = 
    0.4; Kc = 1.0; K = 0.5; L = 0.0; N = 5
    #Equations
    F = ((1/N) * (sum([(V) for i in range(1,N+1)])))
    dXdt = (v1*(K1**n))/((K1**n)+((Z)**n)) - (v2*X)/(K2+X) + 
    (vc*(K*F))/(Kc+(K*F)) + L
    dYdt = (k3*X) - (v4*Y)/(K4+Y)
    dZdt = (k5*Y - ((v6*Z)/(K6+Z)))
    dVdt = (k7*X - ((v8*V)/(K8+V)))
    return dXdt, dYdt, dZdt, dVdt, F
t_span = np.array([0, 120])
t = np.linspace(t_span[0], t_span[1], 2000) 
y0 = [0,0,0,0,0]
soln = solve_ivp(model, t_span, y0, method='RK45', t_eval=t)
t = soln.t; X = soln.y[0]; Y = soln.y[1]; Z = soln.y[2]; V = 
soln.y[3]; F = soln.y[4]
```

I am trying to add the "i" subscript so that I can simulate multiple oscillators, whereas now, I can only simulate 1 oscillator. I have tried everything from adding a forloop using "for i in range(1, N):" to changing the initial condition, to reshaping the vectors, to using the [i] notation. No matter what I do, I always get an indexing error like "I can not index scalar variables". Note that the "R equation" is not included in this model as it can be calculated separately (it outputs a value from 0-1). I know it is possible to model this and I am not sure why that error is showing up. Additionally, I am not sure how to create np.arrays for these differential equations to fix that error, or even how to get started on using the "i" notation. Does anyone have any ideas how to make this work? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You need to increase the variables from numbers in the array to segments in the array

```
def model(t, y):
    X,Y,Z,V = y.reshape([4,-1])
    #Constants
    #Equations
    F = np.mean(V)
    dXdt = (v1*(K1**n))/((K1**n)+((Z)**n)) - (v2*X)/(K2+X) + 
    (vc*(K*F))/(Kc+(K*F)) + L
    dYdt = (k3*X) - (v4*Y)/(K4+Y)
    dZdt = (k5*Y - ((v6*Z)/(K6+Z)))
    dVdt = (k7*X - ((v8*V)/(K8+V)))
    return np.concatenate([dXdt, dYdt, dZdt, dVdt])
```

You will need to construct the initial value with the right length, for instance like the return value as `np.concatenate([X0, Y0, Z0, V0])` with arrays of identical length.

Comment: I followed your advice and I was able to produce a result without an error. However, if I increase the value of "N", nothing changes. In this model you did, it doesn't seem like it takes account of the subscript "i". How can I use your construction to simulate multiple oscillators?

Comment: `N` is only used explicitly in the initial conditions, for instance `X0,Y0,Z0,V0 = np.random.randn([4,N])` or simpler `y0 = np.random.randn(4*N)`. The mean function gets the value `N` internally as array length. All the other operations are element-wise, they only connect variables of the same index.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response! I tried `y0 = np.random.randn(4*N)` but when I create a simple plot, my results are very weird. For instance, the X values become negative. I am not sure if that function is appropriate for trying to simulate multiple oscillators? I initially thought that I had to use the `[i]` notation in order to simulate this model. What do you think?